# Google Analytics incorrect user count

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracking, google-analytics-api

I implemented an App and added Google Analytics V2 to track the usage. At the moment the app is in Alpha-State with an community in G+. I currently added 13 users to be tester of my App - so I guess there are always just 13 users registered.
Google Analytics shows me over 47 active users what is definitly not possible. (Users -> Overview).
Under *acquisition* it shows me as well 47 new users. Just in the graph i can (maybe) see that there where on one day 13 new users which is close to the real number of current users.

If GoogleAnalytics is counting the users wrong - it is useless for me. Am i doing something wrong? Do i need to initialise some advanced settings or should i track users by myself? There is not much code to show, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wrong count of new users while using google analytics for android happens due to **app uninstall and reinstall by the same users**. Whenever your app is reinstalled and used for the first time, GA will track it as a new user.

I assume that since currently testing is going on for your app, there must be multiple reinstalls. If that is the case, then the best option is to not look for user count accuracy now. If only you are doing multiple reinstalls and other users will install only once, then you can also use a filtered view in which your ip is filtered out so as not to count your own traffic.

Comment: sounds realistic! i added now an event to track the device id just once after the app is installed, and i also changed the version of the GoogleAnalytics lib (i was not sure which one it was). Now everything looks like it works. Thanks